# Unable to get an updated value from mobx store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am just trying out mobx, I have a simple component and a store. Whenever the button is pushed, I expect its text to be updated with a new timestamp. However, this doesn't happen and I don't know why. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class State {
  timestamp = Date.now();

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  setTimestamp() {
    this.timestamp = Date.now();
  }
}

const state = new State();

const App = observer(() => {
  const { timestamp, setTimestamp } = state;

  return (
    <View style={s.root}>
      <Button onPress={setTimestamp}>
        {timestamp}
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
});

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8
  }
});

export default App;
```

Also available here: https://snack.expo.io/@pavermakov/react-native-mobx

I use the following dependencies:

```
"mobx": "6.0.1",
"mobx-react": "7.0.0"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this piece of code:

```js
<Button onPress={setTimestamp}>
```

You are losing the `this` context of your `State` class instance. When the button is clicked `this` actually refers to the `Button` element, so there is no `Button.timestamp` to change.
The easiest way to fix this is to `bind` the `setTimestamp` back to the `state` class like this:

```js
 <Button onPress={setTimestamp.bind(state)}>
```